# Somethin' loads mine lo traffic

Tags: networking

I'm having trouble, suddenly, when I had been installed an UPS, traffic is running away.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni lo"

02:50:59.450015 IP 127.0.0.1.50214 > 127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [P.], seq
522:523, ack 244, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486457 ecr
1486432], length 1 02:50:59.450099 IP 127.0.0.1.59783 >
127.0.0.1.50214: Flags [P.], seq 244:245, ack 523, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486457 ecr 1486457], length 1 02:50:59.450150 IP
127.0.0.1.50214 > 127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [.], ack 245, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486457 ecr 1486457], length 0 02:50:59.450221
IP 127.0.0.1.50214 > 127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [P.], seq 523:580, ack
245, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486457 ecr 1486457], length 57
02:50:59.450312 IP 127.0.0.1.59783 > 127.0.0.1.50214: Flags [P.], seq
45:271, ack 580, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486457 ecr
1486457], length 26 02:50:59.471715 IP 127.0.0.1.50281 >
127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [.], ack 266, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486463 ecr 1486453], length 0 02:50:59.487670 IP 127.0.0.1.50214 >
127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [.], ack 271, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486467 ecr 1486457], length 0 02:50:59.550540 IP 127.0.0.1.50214 >
127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [P.], seq 580:581, ack 271, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486482 ecr 1486457], length 1 02:50:59.550656 IP
127.0.0.1.59783 > 127.0.0.1.50214: Flags [P.], seq 271:272, ack 581, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486482 ecr 1486482], length 1
02:50:59.550709 IP 127.0.0.1.50214 > 127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [.], ack
272, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486482 ecr 1486482], length 0
02:50:59.550797 IP 127.0.0.1.50214 > 127.0.0.1.59783: Flags [P.], seq
581:638, ack 272, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486482 ecr
1486482], length 57 02:50:59.550913 IP 127.0.0.1.59783 >
127.0.0.1.50214: Flags [P.], seq 272:298, ack 638, win 518, options [nop,nop,TS val 1486482 ecr 1486482], length 26 ..........................
```

I have used nut for setting it(ups) up.

What I had to do to exit this? It's looks like ping.

Comment: `lo` is your loopback device, aka localhost (127.0.0.1).  Is there a reason you're concerned about the increase on traffic on your own system's localhost in communicating to itself?

Comment: No it isn't, but I want to stop it, because I have an applet with networking graph and I couldn't see real network use because of it.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is based on comments on the original question

Typically one wouldn't need to concern themselves with their own `lo` traffic.

As you said, you have a network monitor graph applet.  If your applet can't distinguish between interfaces its not doing its job, really.

Based on what I can see, `nut` is used to communicate with your UPS.  That's what the increased communication is.  If you don't want this increased local-system traffic, then don't have your UPS communicating with the computer.  That may reduce the networking traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Tomas, maybe you was right. 
But, now I had realized my own problem ... 
It was in one program which had been installed about 6 days ago in /opt, called WinPower  from http://www.mustek.de (MonitorSoftware). Maybe it was pinging this USB (ttyUSB0) host.

After when I remembered it and I deleted it, traffic became normal phenomenon. :DD

Thanks, dear friends :DD. With coming ;)